# PostgreSQL: Resetting password of PostgreSQL on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, unix

In Ubuntu, I installed PostgreSQL database and created a superuser for the server.

If I forgot the password of the postgresql superuser, how can I reset it (the password) for that user?

I tried uninstalling it and then installing it again but the previously created superuser is retained.

Answer (score 300, accepted):

Assuming you're the administrator of the machine, Ubuntu has granted you the right to **sudo** to run any command as any user.
Also assuming you did not restrict the rights in the `pg_hba.conf` file (in the `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main` directory), it should contain this line as the first rule:

```properties
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket  
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

(About the file location: `9.1` is the major postgres version and `main` the name of your "cluster". It will differ if using a newer version of postgres or non-default names. Use the `pg_lsclusters` command to obtain this information for your version/system).

Anyway, if the `pg_hba.conf` file does not have that line, edit the file, add it, and reload the service with `sudo service postgresql reload`.

Then you should be able to log in with `psql` as the postgres superuser with this shell command:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Once inside psql, issue the SQL command:

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'newpassword';
```

In this command, `postgres` is the name of a superuser. If the user whose password is forgotten was `ritesh`, the command would be:

```
ALTER USER ritesh PASSWORD 'newpassword';
```

References: [PostgreSQL 9.1.13 Documentation, Chapter 19. Client Authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/client-authentication.html)

Keep in mind that you need to type **postgres** with a single **S** at the end

If leaving the password in clear text in the history of commands or the server log is a problem, psql provides an interactive meta-command to avoid that, as an alternative to `ALTER USER ... PASSWORD`:

```
\password username
```

It asks for the password with a double blind input, then hashes it according to the [`password_encryption`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-PASSWORD-ENCRYPTION) setting and issue the `ALTER USER` command to the server with the hashed version of the password, instead of the clear text version.

Comment: i used your method my super user name is ritesh my pg_hba.conf is that as what you mentioned.i run command "ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'newpassword' ;" console is showing 'ALTER ROLE' .then i exited using ctrl+c after that i run a command createuser .it is showing to input a password i entered newpassword but it is giving me error "createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "ritesh" ".how to create a user and what should be password for this command??

Comment: If you want to change password for `ritesh`, change the SQL above to `ALTER USER ritesh PASSWORD 'newpassword'`

Comment: you should restart postgres after change pg_hba.conf....

Comment: No need to restart, just use pg_ctl reload.

Comment: it has partially worked. I have added a new line to pg_hba.config as `local all all password` and created a new role using this command: `create role my_new_user login password 'my_password_here' valid until 'infinity' superuser;` and used this new account instead of `postgres`

Comment: what should I do if password not changing after it? I did `\password postgres`, set password `qwe123`, but after invoke `sudo apt update` and input password see an error `Sorry, try again.`

Comment: @EgoPingvina: "Sorry, try again" is a message from the `sudo` command. The password that `sudo` is asking is for your shell account. The password set with `\password postgres` is for the database account. These two are independant.